# Page not found - Angular 4

Tags: angular

Does anybody have an idea how to redirect to another url when a page is not found in Angular 4, because `{ path: "**",  redirectTo: "/error" },` seems to be not working (at least for me)?

Comment: make sure you have route defined for path "error" in your routes configuration, if yes add pathMatch: 'full' to the definition as well { path: "**",  redirectTo: "/error", pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: Thanks, it works <3

Comment: you are welcome! please accept my answer if it resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have route defined for path "error" in your routes configuration, if yes add pathMatch: 'full' to the definition as well

```
{ path: "error",  component: ErrorComponent  },
{ path: "**",  redirectTo: "/error", pathMatch: 'full'  }
```